# cannot find symbol variable key1

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I don't understand why I'm getting this error message `cannot find symbol   variable key1`. I have key1 and key 2 defined at the top in private Strings, yet I still get this error. Should I be including key1 and key2 in my decrypt method?
Thank you. All suggestions are welcome.
**Edit: My apologies, key1 and key2 are not defined in private strings.**

```
import edu.duke.*;

public class CaesarCipherTwoKeys {
    private String alphabetLower;
    private String alphabetUpper;
    private String shiftedAlphabetLower1;
    private String shiftedAlphabetUpper1;
    private String shiftedAlphabetLower2;
    private String shiftedAlphabetUpper2;
    private int mainKey1;
    private int mainKey2;
    public CaesarCipherTwoKeys(int key1, int key2) {
        alphabetLower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        alphabetUpper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        shiftedAlphabetLower1 = alphabetLower.substring(key1) + alphabetLower.substring(0,key1);
        shiftedAlphabetUpper1 = alphabetUpper.substring(key1) + alphabetUpper.substring(0,key1);
        shiftedAlphabetLower2 = alphabetLower.substring(key2) + alphabetLower.substring(0,key2);
        shiftedAlphabetUpper2 = alphabetUpper.substring(key2) + alphabetUpper.substring(0,key2);
        mainKey1 = key1;
        mainKey2 = key2;
    }
    public String encrypt(String input) {
        StringBuilder encryptedInput = new StringBuilder(input);
        OOCaesarCipher oocc1 = new OOCaesarCipher(mainKey1);
        OOCaesarCipher oocc2 = new OOCaesarCipher(mainKey2);

        for (int index=0; index < input.length(); index++) {
            if (index % 2 == 0 || index == 0) {
                encryptedInput.replace(index,index+1,oocc1.encrypt(input.substring(index,index+1)));
            }
            else {
                encryptedInput.replace(index,index+1,oocc2.encrypt(input.substring(index,index+1)));
            }
        }
        return encryptedInput.toString();
   }
   public String decrypt(String input) {
      CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk= new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(26 - key1, 26 - key2); 
      String decrypted = cctk.encrypt(input); 
      return decrypted;

     }
    }
```

This is where the problem is:

```
public String decrypt(String input) {
          CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk= new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(26 - key1, 26 - key2); 
          String decrypted = cctk.encrypt(input); 
          return decrypted;

         }
```

Comment: *I have key1 and key 2 defined at the top in private Strings*. I don't see it.

Comment: I dont see where you declare key1 and key2, just `mainKey1` and `mainKey2`

Comment: Voting to close as: *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error*

Comment: Use mainkey, key1 is not visible at the place you use it

Comment: Can key1 be moved to where mainkey is? It seems key1 is useless at its current position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do when you get "cannot find symbol" error is to check where the symbol is actually declared. Running a text editor search works fine for that.

Look for the variable with the name that you specify in the scope where it is referenced. In addition to local variables defined above the point of reference, these items are also in scope:

- Method and constructor parameters are in scope for the entire method/constructor,
- Instance variables are in scope for constructors and instance methods
- Static variables are in scope for all methods and constructors

Now let's look at your code. You write this in your constructor:

```
public CaesarCipherTwoKeys(int key1, int key2) {
    ...
    mainKey1 = key1;
    mainKey2 = key2;
}
```

`key1` and `key2` are constructor parameters. They are in scope for the constructor, but once the constructor has finished, both `key1` and `key2` go out of scope; you cannot access them from `decrypt`.

`mainKey1` and `mainKey2`, however, remain in scope inside of `decrypt`, because they are instance variables:

```
CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk= new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(26 - mainKey1, 26 - mainKey2);
```